# Does a spark cluster gets provisioned even if I use python shell with Glue

Tags: python, aws-glue

I wanted to know if we use Python Shell with Glue, does it still provision a Spark cluster in the background?

Comment: No, Glue Spark cluster is provisioned only for job types Glue ETL (`glueetl`) or Glue Streaming (`gluestreaming`) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job.html

Comment: Thanks, there was a discussion where someone mentioned that it will be costly and will take more time to run Python Shell through Glue VS executing the python through aws airflow and python operator. Based on this then, that statement is not true.